# "Yield" doesn't work in binding.scala

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

Several days ago I read about binding.scala and I found it so cool therefore I decided to write my own single page app.

The problem is that I'm trying to add "li" items into "ul" element, but it seems like the component **Want** doesn't see updates.

The code below:

```
case class Movie(title: Var[String], raring: Var[Int], watched: Var[Boolean])
var movies = Vars.empty[Movie]

@dom def Want = {
println(movies.bind, "!@#!@#!@#!")
<div class="want">
  <ul>
    {for (movie <- movies.value) yield {
    <li>
      <div>
        <span>
          {movie.title.bind}
        </span>
        <button onclick={event: Event => {
          event.preventDefault()
          movies.value.remove(movies.value.indexOf(movie))
          println(movies.value)
        }}></button>
      </div>
    </li>
  }}
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I change **movies** nothing happens.

UPDATE

After the comment below I updated the code:

```
def remove(movie:Movie) = {
    movies.value.-=(movie)}
@dom def Want = {
println(movies, "!@#!@#!@#!")
<div class="want">
  <ul>
    {for (movie <- movies.bind) yield {
    <li>
      <div>
        <span>
          {movie.title.bind}
        </span>
        <button onclick={event: Event => {
          event.preventDefault()
          remove(movie)
        }}></button>
      </div>
    </li>
  }}
  </ul>
</div>
```

}
However, the code doesn't work.

Comment: I gave a downvote to your question, because your updated code is entirely in a mess. You will be more likely to get helped if you create a producible example on https://scalafiddle.io/ and link to it from this question.

Answer (score 2):

Please change `for (movie <- movies.value)` to `for (movie <- movies)`.

According to [the Scaladoc of value method](https://static.javadoc.io/com.thoughtworks.binding/unidoc_2.12/11.0.0-M3/com/thoughtworks/binding/Binding$$Vars.html#value:scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[A]withVars.this.Proxy):

> Note: This method must not be invoked inside a `@dom` method body.

Comment: maybe there is a mistake: Please change for (movie <- movies.value) to for (movie <- movies.value)